# How to close the front application window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to close the front window of my application. How is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`[myWindow close]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close) or [`[myWindow performClose:nil]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performClose:).
Use [`[NSApplication keyWindow]`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/keyWindow) to get the key window if needed. If you want just the front-most one, grab the first one from [`[NSApplication orderedWindows]`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/orderedWindows).

Comment: Above is not working for me. Showing following error
 error: 'myWindow' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: The point was: call `close` or `performClose:` on your front window.